# unexpected output from ternary operator

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] num = {1,4,3,6,8,5,3,1,9,7};
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<num.length ;i++)
        {
            for(int j =i+1;j<num.length;j++)
            {
                result += (num[i]==num[j]?1:0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

I dont understand why i am getting `2` as output, can someone please explain.

Comment: Please edit your question and apply proper formatting, so the code is at least readable.

Comment: Was it really hard to retype your homework, so you just posted a *screenshot* ? Also, while retyping, you could already test it yourself, unless you were in the middle of exam.

Comment: sorry, it's not the retype homework. I can't uderstand the section here: numbers[i]==numbers[j] --> does mean it numbers [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10] == ... likewise  i=0; i<10  i++.?

Comment: @Bilguunenkhee copy paste the code in question and remove the image.

Comment: Please edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exact code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] num = {1,4,3,6,8,5,3,1,9,7};
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<num.length ;i++){
            for(int j =i+1;j<num.length;j++){
                result += (num[i]==num[j]?1:0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

First time `result += (num[i]==num[j]?1:0)` will be true when `i=0` , `j=7` making **result = 1;**

Second time `result += (num[i]==num[j]?1:0)` will be true when `i=2` , `j=6` making **result = 2;**

Comment: does it not mean if true will be 1 or else 0? Can you explain 1=0? and j=7 means 7 numbers?  Also I don't understand (num[i] == num[j]).

Comment: if `num[i] == num[j]` is true the output from this will be 1 else 0

Comment: Yes.Can you explain it a bit more the result was 2 of the print result?

Comment: see first time when `num[0] == num[7]` hppened the result became=0+1, next time when `num[2] == num[6]` happened then result was already 1 and now it became 1+1 = 2;

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I just have seen the wrong prospect.